# Is $f(x) = x^{10}-x^5+1$ solvable by radicals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

> Is $f(x) = x^{10}-x^5+1$ solvable by radicals?

So far I've showed that $f$ is irreducible because if we let $y=x^5$ then $f(y)=y^2-y+1$ which is irreducible because it has a negative discriminant. I also know that $f$ has no real roots so I've concluded that $Gal(L_f/\mathbb{Q}) \subset S_{10}$ and that there is a 10-cycle and a transposition in $Gal(L_f/\mathbb{Q})$. However I have no clue as to what $Gal(L_f/\mathbb{Q})$ could be.

Comment: You can find the roots using your substitution.

Comment: First, that $\;\text{Gal}(L_f/\Bbb Q)\subset S_{10}\;$ is true whatever the roots of $\;f\;$ are. Second, if you *really* deduced already that this group contains a $\;10\,-$ cycle and a transposition then it is the whole $\;S_{10}\;$ , as any two of those cycles generate the whole permutation group...

Comment: Polynomial is reducible.  $(x^2-x+1)(x^8 + x^7 - x^5 - x^4 - x^3 + x + 1)$

Comment: Have you noticed that the roots of $y^2 - y + 1$ are $\exp(\pi i /3)$ and $\exp(-\pi i /3)$?

Comment: @sharding4 So if you make a substitution and you end up with an irreducible polynomial, does that polynomial divides the original one?

Comment: No.  For example $x^4-x^2+1$ can be transformed in to $y^2-y+1$ by the substitution $y=x^2$, but it is irreducible.

Comment: @CamiloEscobar OTOH, you _cannot_ say that 'we make this substitution and end up with an irreducible polynomial, therefore the original polynomial is irreducible' without a lot of additional justification.

Comment: @DonAntonio So I just realized that the polynomial is not reducible so there is not necessarily a 10-cycle in my Galois group, however, wouldn't an n-cycle and a transposition generate the whole of S_n only if n is prime

Comment: @CamiloEscobar No, that is true for any $\;n\;$ ...yet the transposition must be carefully chosen according to what $\;n\,$ cycle was chosen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you multiply by $x^5+1$, you get $x^{15}+1 =0$.  So the roots are all the 15th roots of $-1$.  Throw out the five 5th-roots, and you have your solutions.  So the answer is "yes".

Comment: +1 Very nice, do you mind sharing the motivation for this?

Comment: @Ovi Thanks.  But I don't think there's much motivation.  I just noticed the part of the sum of cubes factoring and multiplied by the other part.

Comment: Ah okay (character limit)

Comment: But also one may recognize that $X^2-X+1=\Phi_6(X)$, the cyclotomic polynomial whose roots are the primitive sixth roots of unity. The fifth roots of these all are $30$-th roots of unity: the eight primitive thirtieth roots, together with the two primitive cube roots of unity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course.

Let $x+\frac{1}{x}=a$.

Hence,
$$x^{10}-x^5+1=x^{10}+x^7-x^7+x^6-x^5-x^6+1=$$
$$=(x^2-x+1)(x^7(x+1)-x^5-(x^3-1)(x+1))=$$
$$=(x^2-x+1)(x^8+x^7-x^5-x^4-x^3+x+1)=$$
$$=(x^2-x+1)x^4\left(x^4+\frac{1}{x^4}+x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}-x-\frac{1}{x}-1\right)=$$
$$=(x^2-x+1)x^4(a^4-4a^2+2+a^3-3a-a-1)=$$
$$=(x^2-x+1)x^4(a^4+a^3-4a^2-4a+1)=$$
$$=(x^2-x+1)x^4\left(a^2+\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}a+\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}\right)\left(a^2+\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}a+\frac{-3+\sqrt5}{2}\right)...$$